# Update HTML value for each JSON Value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to update each value from a div on a view by getting a JSON from a controllers action.
I'm currently able to target every div but I do not know how to read every JSON value.

This is my div:

```
 <div class="progress" style="background: white" value="@item.CompletionRate"
     data-acr="@item.Acronym"></div>
```

This is my Ajax getting the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/ModelsUpdate",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $('.progress').each(function () {
            // JSON condition should be here
        });
        drawCircles();
    }
});
```

The condition should be something like:

```
var acr= $(this).attr('acr'); //referring to .progress data-acr field
each(result){
    if(result.Acronym == acr){
        $(this).data('value', result.CompletitionRate)
    }
```

JSON looks like this:

```
[{"Name":"Raw To Common","Acronym":"RTC","Status":"Running","CompletionRate":11,"Started":"\/Date(1513220400000)\/","Ended":null},{"Name":"ePack","Acronym":"EPK","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Finished Goods Long Constrained","Acronym":"FLC","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Raw Material Long Term Constrained","Acronym":"RLC","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Finished Goods Long Term Unconstrained","Acronym":"FLU","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Finished Goods Short Term Constrained","Acronym":"FSC","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Finished Goods Short Term Unconstrained","Acronym":"FSU","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Raw Materials Long Term Unconstrained","Acronym":"RLU","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null},{"Name":"Finished Goods Long Term Fixed Supply","Acronym":"FLF","Status":"Not Started","CompletionRate":0,"Started":null,"Ended":null}]
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public JsonResult ModelsUpdate()
    {
        DateTime minDate = DateTime.Today;
        DayOfWeek todayDay = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime resultminDate = new DateTime();
        resultminDate = CalculateminDate(minDate,todayDay);


        var viewModel = CacheHelper.Current.Get(resultminDate);

        return Json(viewModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: that depends on what json you're returning from server

Comment: can you share your server-side code?

Comment: Need to see the JSON and for you to tell us which fields you want from it. I'm guessing maybe you need a loop, but it's impossible to be sure without seeing the data structure.

Comment: @ADyson ready guys, I've updated the question.

Comment: @derloopkat done.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var result = [{
    "Name": "Raw To Common",
    "Acronym": "RTC",
    "Status": "Running",
    "CompletionRate": 11,
    "Started": "\/Date(1513220400000)\/",
    "Ended": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "ePack",
    "Acronym": "EPK",
    "Status": "Not Started",
    "CompletionRate": 0,
    "Started": null,
    "Ended": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "Finished Goods Long Constrained",
    "Acronym": "FLC",
    "Status": "Not Started",
    "CompletionRate": 0,
    "Started": null,
    "Ended": null
  }
]

$(".progress").each(function(element) {
  var acr = $(this).data('acr');
  var item = result.find(item => item.Acronym == acr);
  if (item) {
    $(this).attr("value", item.CompletionRate);
    $(this).text(item.Acronym + ' - ' + item.Status);
  } else {
    console.log(acr, "Not found.");
  }
});
```

```css
.progress {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress" style="background: white" value="0" data-acr="RTC"></div>
<div class="progress" style="background: white" value="0" data-acr="EPK"></div>
<div class="progress" style="background: white" value="0" data-acr="FLC"></div>
```

Comment: I will try to use this approach, but still need to insert it to the HTML value , how to do that?

Comment: @Marcelo insert HTML value - where?

Comment: Getting undefined on console.

Comment: Inside the div thats on the question, you can see it has a value attribute.

Comment: @Marcelo, you have only one div in your Html. Do you mean to create one div per value?

Comment: @derloopkat div is inside a foreach, it shows a progressbar for a list of cards in my web.

Comment: @Marcelo, okay.

Comment: @Igor I got it to work by changing $(this).attr('acr') to $(this).data('acr'), my mistake. Now...how to only get item.CompletitionRate and assign it to value inside div.